# Can't move `viminfo` file - &viminfo reverts upon loading vim

Tags: vimrc, viminfo

I'm trying to change the location of the `viminfo` file.

Why does the value of `&viminfo` revert after it is set in `vimrc`?

**TL;DR:**

In my `vimrc` I have:

```
set nocompatible
exec "set viminfo+=n".expand($XDG_DATA_HOME)."/vim/viminfo"
echom &viminfo
```

I've noticed that `echo &viminfo` from command mode shows the *previous* version of `&viminfo` even though the `echom` inside `vimrc` shows that `&viminfo` was correctly (but temporarily) updated.

I'd suspect `autocommand`, but `ag -ul viminfo` only shows my `vimrc` and the `viminfo` file itself.

Why does the value of `&viminfo` change after I explicitly set it?

**Full description**

```
@ravi@boxy:~$ vim --version | head -1
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 05 2016 16:48:20)
```

I start `vim` with VIMINIT set to honour the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

```
@ravi@boxy:~$ echo $VIMINIT
let $MYVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc"|set nocp|exec "set viminfo+=n".expand($XDG_DATA_HOME)."/vim/viminfo"|echom &viminfo|source $MYVIMRC
@ravi@boxy:~$
```

For belts and braces, I also have in my `vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
" Location of the viminfo file
exec "set viminfo+=n".expand($XDG_DATA_HOME)."/vim/viminfo"
echom &viminfo
```

Now I remove the existing `~/.viminfo`, start `vim`, then exit:

```
@ravi@boxy:~$ rm ~/.viminfo 
@ravi@boxy:~$ vim
'100,<50,s10,h,n/home/ravi/.local/share/vim/viminfo
'100,<50,s10,h,n/home/ravi/.local/share/vim/viminfo
Press ENTER or type command to continue
@ravi@boxy:~$ file ~/.viminfo 
/home/ravi/.viminfo: ASCII text
@ravi@boxy:~$
```

The `&viminfo` variable gets printed twice because of the belt and braces, but as you can see, the file is still created at the default location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

This seems to be a bug in `vim` where `set nocompatible` is not [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and doesn't follow the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

As a workaround, either:

1. Ensure that you `set nocompatible` (or the equivalent `set nocp`) only *once*, and *at the top* of your `vimrc`.
2. Don't set it if it's already set:

   ```
   if &compatible | set nocompatible | endif " Avoid side effects if `nocp` already set
   ```

**Explanation and bug illustration**

From [`:help compatible`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) (empahsis mine):

> This is a special kind of option, because when it's set or reset,
>   other options are also changed as a side effect.  **CAREFUL: Setting or
>   resetting this option can have a lot of unexpected effects**: Mappings
>   are interpreted in another way, undo behaves differently, etc.  If you
>   set this option in your vimrc file, you should probably put it at the
>   very start.

Note that `&viminfo` is **not** listed in the side-effects, however the following lines clearly show the side effect upon `&viminfo`:

```
set nocompatible
set viminfo+=nWatch-my-viminfo-file-location-be-ignored
echom &viminfo
set nocompatible " do side effects even though nocomptible is already set
echom 'After 2nd "set nocompatible":'
echom &viminfo
```

Output:

> ```
> '100,<50,s10,h,nWatch-my-viminfo-file-location-be-ignored
> After 2nd "set nocompatible":
> '100,<50,s10,h
> ```

`vim --version | head -1`

> `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 05 2016 16:48:20)`

---

**Resolution**

I have raised two GitHub issues regarding this:

- [Undocumented "set nocompatible" side effect upon &viminfo](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1132)
- [`set nocompatible` not idempotent - setting produces side effects when already set](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1131)

See also StackExchange's question: [How to tell VIM to store the viminfo file somewhere else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286866/how-to-tell-vim-to-store-the-viminfo-file-somewhere-else)

Comment: `"Ensure that you set nocompatible (or the equivalent set nocp) only once, and at the top of your vimrc"` -> Actually, you don't need to do put this in your vimrc at all, ever. Using `nocompatible` is the default if there is a vimrc file! Vim *only* loads in compatible mode if there's no vimrc. This is mentioned in [`:help 'nocompatible'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27nocompatible%27) in the paragraph after the one you quoted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite a while now, but I am just mentioning this for future readers.

I was facing a similar issue while trying to change the location for viminfo file in vimrc. At last setting the value of `viminfofile` option worked for me.

Added the following to my vimrc:

```
set viminfofile=D:\vim\viminfo
```

*It works for me on windows with vim 8.2*

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Does this keep the viminfo file in the "root" (or system) vim directory, or is `D` an external drive (I'm used to seeing `C`)? I wouldn't advise that.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `D`, in my case, is the data drive(partition). It can also be `C` or any other drive.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to use the 'n' option but what works for me and is not in the documentation is:

set viminfofile=~/.vim/viminfo

(I got this idea from tanish's window answer above. Turns out it works on linux too! I'm using vim 9.0.)